# Title not working on react-navigation createStackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using `createStackNavigator` inside `createBottomTabNavigator` from `react-navigation` in my app. I want to have a title on my screen. Following  [React Navigation's tutorial](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) I've implemented it this way:

```
createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: createStackNavigator(
       {screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: () => { title: 'Home'}}),
      ...
    },
```

However, nothing is displayed in the navigation bar. I've also tried `headerTitle` though no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 ways of setting `navigationOptions`, object or function

**Object**

```
{
    screen: HomePage,
    navigationOptions: { title: 'Home' }
}
```

**Function that return an object**

```
{
    screen: HomePage,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
       return { title: 'Home' }
    }
}
```

Your code doesn't work is due to you have error in your arrow function, you should add a bracket around the body so that it returning the object.

```
{ screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: () => ({ title: 'Home'}) }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Another way of doing this is `{ screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: () => {return { title: 'Home'}} }`

Comment: When I pass a plain object `createStackNavigator({screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: { title: 'Home'} })`, I get an error: The component for route 'navigationOptions' must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
...
navigationOptions: MyScreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:

import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator';
...
navigationOptions: MyNavigator,
}

Comment: you have define your route wrongly, the `createStackNavigator` should be a object with key for example `createStackNavigator({ Home: { screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: { .... }}})` please refer to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: You were right. It worked when I turned it into a key-value pair instead of object.

Answer (score 1):

navigationOptions shouldn't be a function, instead, is a JSON. So, remove the arrows and do it like this:

```
createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: createStackNavigator(
   {screen: HomePage, navigationOptions: { title: 'Home'},
  ...
},
```

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html clearly shows an example as a function. However, I tried it anyway and got an error: `The component for route 'navigationOptions' must be a React component.`